# FRED data: aggregate quarterly data into annual

Tags: r, aggregate, quantmod

I need to convert quarterly data into yearly, by summing over 4 quarters in each year. When I searched stackoverflow.com, I found that using a function to sum over periods, seem to work. However, the format did not match, so I couldn't work with the converted year data array with the other arrays

For example, annual data in FRED looks as follows:

```
2009-01-01       12126.078
2010-01-01       12739.542
2011-01-01       13352.255
2012-01-01       14061.878
2013-01-01       14444.823
```

However, when I changed the data using the following function:

```
library("quantmod")
library(zoo)
library(mFilter)
library(nleqslv)

fredsym <- c("PROPINC")
quarter.proprietors_income <- PROPINC

## convert to annual
as.year <- function(x) as.integer(as.yearqtr(x)) # a new function
annual.proprietors_income <- aggregate(quarter.proprietors_income, as.yearqtr, sum) # sum over quarters
```

it changes from this:

```
2016-01-01 1327.613
2016-04-01 1339.493
2016-07-01 1346.067
2016-10-01 1354.560
2017-01-01 1380.221
2017-04-01 1378.637
2017-07-01 1381.911
2017-10-01 1403.114
```

to this:

```
2011 4574.669
2012 4965.486
2013 5138.968
2014 5263.208
2015 5275.225
2016 5367.733
2017 5543.883
```

What I need is having an annual data but with the original YYYY-MM-DD format, and it should appear as 01-01 for each yearly data.. Otherwise it doesn't work with other annual data...

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Using `DF` in the Note below use `cut` as shown:

```
aggregate(DF["value"], list(year = as.Date(cut(as.Date(DF$Date), "year"))), sum)
```

giving:

```
        year    value
1 2016-01-01 5367.733
2 2017-01-01 5543.883
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Date value
2016-01-01 1327.613
2016-04-01 1339.493
2016-07-01 1346.067
2016-10-01 1354.560
2017-01-01 1380.221
2017-04-01 1378.637
2017-07-01 1381.911
2017-10-01 1403.114"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: quarter.proprietors_income from FRED does not seem to have date or value label in it, how can I control that and apply to your example??

Comment: The answer is to the question and the question had date and value columns.

Comment: yes... but it did not have a column name for that... How can I access to the first column...? Sorry for poor question.. I'm a novice..

Comment: f.y.i. when I typed  class(quarter.proprietors_income) 


[1] "xts" "zoo"

Comment: The question did not provide input in reproducible form so the answer did. If you copy and paste the input in the Note at the end and then code in the body of the answer you should get the same result as in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I found that, the aggregate command makes the class into zoo. No more xts to be remained as time series.

Alternatively, apply.yearly seems to work.

```
annual.proprietors_income <- apply.yearly(xts(quarter.proprietors_income),sum)
```

This is now in xts. BUt the thing is they show mon-day as ending quarter as YYYY-10-01 for each year. How can I make it into YYYY-01-01....